# Best way of De-Duplication Sql Server when data is in billions

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Could anyone please suggest approach for efficient de-duplication in sql server whn i have huge amount of data of range of billions,

I used CTE and Duplication using deletion of duplicate records from main table and then taking those duplicates in a temp table removing duplicates in temp table and insert these records back to table.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the table structure including indexes? What percentage of the table are duplicates?

Comment: most of the columns are nvarchars and indexing on key columns, duplication is quite low it was about .00002%

Comment: There are many duplicates for this question about duplicates, just try some of the solutions. It is possible to delete the duplicates in place quite fast, without any temp table. Performance is also often discussed in the comments.

Comment: Please tell if you have a primary key or if rows are exact duplicates. Then I could suggest what solution to try first..